# How to combine ST_Intersection() and St_Area() into a single query?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a `queried` layer and a `buildings` layer and I am currently running the following query to find areas of intersection using the [St_Intersection()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) function inside the **QGIS DB Manager** plugin:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(buildings.geom, queried.geom) as inter from buildings, queried
```

[image: ST_Intersection]

(*I'm hoping the function is correct as it's been running for over an hour now...*)

---

But I want to repeat this and combine it using [ST_Area()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) so that the output layer constains all intersection features with another column in the table showing the area.

How could I combine these two functions into one query?

Comment: It's unlikely this query is correct (unless every shape overlaps). See the documentation on how to use a `JOIN` clause utilizing `ST_Intersects` to constrain the query to only overlapping geometries. Then you have a number of ways to  access the intersection geometry... My preference is via an inline query with a `FROM ( SELECT ... )` block (also documented)

Comment: @Vince - Thanks, I will take a closer look at the docs =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do ST_Intersection in a subquery

```
SELECT a.intersection, ST_Area(a.intersection) FROM
(SELECT ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 76 373, 407 450, 361 168, 76 373 ))'),
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 230 460, 520 232, 415 502, 230 460 ))')) AS intersection) a;
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your answer. I'll try and incorporate that into what I am doing :)

Comment: This answer does not address how to properly JOIN multiple rows from muliple tables with a spatial relationship constraint.

Comment: True, is is not a comprehensive answer but it is addressing somehow the question in the title as it stands now "How to combine ST_Intersection() and St_Area() into a single query?".